# Creating table using the values stored in a vector

Tags: c++

```
void distances(vector<string> &cities, vector<double> &xcoord, vector<double> &ycoord, vector<double> &dist) 
// Function used to calculate the distances between the different cities and then storing it into a vector.
{
double dist1;
for (int i =0; i < cities.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j =0; j < cities.size(); j++)
    {
        double dist1 = sqrt(    ((xcoord.at(i) - xcoord.at(j))*(xcoord.at(i) - xcoord.at(j))) + ((ycoord.at(i) - ycoord.at(j))*(ycoord.at(i) - ycoord.at(j)))    );
        dist.push_back(dist1);

    }
}
```

}

I am using this function to calculate the distances between 10 different cities. I then stored the calculated distances into a vector. I now want to format it into a table. How would I do that using the vector that I have created?

Comment: Does `vector::data()` do the trick for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By formatting it into a table, do you mean arranging it into a 2D vector, as if it were a table? Because, you can do that by passing dist as a 2D vector instead of a uni-dimensional one.

You should this time pass dist as a vector of vectors, initialized to be a 9 x 9 vector (or a cities.size() x cities.size() vector) like this:

```
vector< vector< double > > vector_I_Intend_To_Pass_As_Argument; //Pass this vector as the dist argument when calling the distances method
vector_I_Intend_To_Pass_As_Argument = vector< vector< double > >(cities.size()); //Or just 9, if you want to hardcode it
for(int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++)
{
      vector_I_Intend_To_Pass_As_Argument[i] = vector< double >(cities.size());
}
```